# Muted Youtube Video Player is being unmuted everytime i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe, youtube

So I dynamically add a YouTube video on my page, I setup the onReadyState function to mute() whenever is placed.

```
t.player = new window.YT.Player($iframePlaceholder, {
                    videoId: id,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 400,
                    playerVars: {
                        autoplay: 1,
                        loop: 1,
                        rel: 0,
                        fs: 1,
                        controls: 0,
                        showinfo: 0,
                        modestbranding: 1,
                        iv_load_policy: 3,
                        origin: document.location.origin,
                        playlist: t.getVideoId()
                    },
                    events: {
                        'onReady': t.onPlayerReady.bind(t),
                        'onStateChange': t.onStateChange.bind(t)
                    }
                });
```

And this is onPlayerReady function

```
onPlayerReady: function() {
        this.player.playVideo();
        this.player.mute();
    }
```

It works fine for the first time, but whenever I refresh the page, it goes unmuted.
Tried accessing this way but I had a cross-browser error due to the iframe.

```
$('iframe').contents().find('video').each(function () 
{
   this.mute();

});
```

I guessed I would have to iterate through all the video iframes and try to mute them on document ready. But how can I achieve this? Any ideas?

Thanks.